# Trapping "Maximum size of callout request or response" exception

Tags: governorlimits, http

Salesforce limits: "Maximum size of callout request or response: 3MB", is there a way to "trap this exception", to gracefully handle responses that end up being over 3mb? I'm hitting these limits and it's resulting in an uncaught exception even in a *try/catch block*

Gov. Limits:
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm

Http Classes (where I've been looking for a method):
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_restful_http.htm

Comment: This is now 6/12 MB. Anyway to overcome 12 MB limit?? :) As Maximum size of callout request or response (HTTP request or Web services call) is 6 MB for synchronous Apex or 12 MB for asynchronous Apex, so at max 12 MB attachment can only be sent to Amazon S3 using HTTP request.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't unique to this limit. System.LimitException is uncatchable and means that your script will be killed, even if it happens inside a try/catch block.

I don't know of any good way to handle this for **responses** within the same context. However, if you make the callout in a different context (JS remoting, etc.) and add some sort of success/error logging you can check your logs from the main context to see if the callout completed successfully.

If you want to check the size of your **request** prior to sending it out the best way is to run Limits.getHeapsize() prior to and after building the request and compare the two values.